# Как лучше организовать хранение данных нескольких таблиц в одном поле?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Использую MariaDB 10.11.5
Имеется таблица `myservices` с данными к аккаунтам. Среди прочих полей в ней есть 2 поля с данными к резервному аккаунту электронной почты.

```
reserve_type Индекс enum('google', 'yahoo', 'mail_ru', 'rambler', 'yandex' ...
reserve_id   Индекс bigint(20)
```

Соответственно в этой базе данных есть одноимённые таблицы с данными к аккаунтам эл. почты `google`, `yahoo`, `mail_ru` и т.д.
И поле reserve_type указывает на таблицу, а поле reserve_id на ID в этой таблице.

Чем плоха такая структура организации данных?
Какой вид будет иметь запрос, когда нужно будет получить email из таблицы `yahoo`, который не указан как резервный в таблице `myservices` для reserve_type 'yahoo'.
И как искать по такой таблице?
И главный вопрос: Имеется ли вариант лучше организовать структуру таблиц в БД для подобной задачи?

Comment: и зачем это  разбивать на множество таблиц? зы: если почта будет с доменом `vasya.ru` то с каким enum значнием вы будете это хранить?

Comment: *Чем плоха такая структура организации данных?* Не соответствует нормальным формам. *Имеется ли вариант лучше организовать структуру таблиц в БД для подобной задачи?* Да, конечно. Одна сущность = одна таблица.